# Why aren't my dictionary values being stored as integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that returns the number of occurrences of each letter in a string:

```
def count_all(text):
    text = text.lower()
    counts = {}
    for char in text:
        if char not in counts:
            counts.setdefault(char,[1])
        else:
            counts[char] = counts[char] + 1
    print(counts)

count_all('banana')
```

But when I try to run it I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countall.py", line 11, in <module>
    count_all('banana')
  File "countall.py", line 8, in count_all
    counts[char] = counts[char] + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I suspect it's reading the value of key `char` as a list with a single item rather than an integer, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm not having any trouble with creating keys for each letter and assigning their value to 1, as this is what gets printed out when I comment out the `else` clause:

```
Mac:python mac$ python3 countall.py
{'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'n': [1]}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suspect it's reading the value of key char as a list with a single item rather than an integer

Exactly, because you set it to a list: `counts.setdefault(char,[1])`. Just don't do that and it'll work: `counts.setdefault(char,1)`. `setdefault` is in fact unnecessary, since you already checked that `char not in counts`, so you can just do `counts[char] = 1`.

Also note that Python already has this algorithm built in:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('banana')
Counter({'a': 3, 'n': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I didn't notice that, I got the `[]` operator for returning index values mixed up with the one for creating lists. And thanks for showing me the algorithm too, right now I'm gonna keep working on this as it's a beginner exercise to understand the basics of the language but that will definitely come in handy in the future.